# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'TodoModel' in type cast

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Hi I'm new to Flutter and having a problem.
I want to add data fetched from Firestore to a variable which is List type but I get the error. I spent hours for this to figure it out but not working well.

Does anybody know how I get this error?

#### toto_model.dart

```
class TodoModel {
  String _title = '';
  bool _done = false;
  int _id = 1;
  String _docId = '';

  TodoModel(String title, bool done, int id, String docId) {
    this._title = title;
    this._done = done;
    this._id = id;
    this._docId = docId;
  }

  String get title => _title;
  bool get done => _done;
  int get id => _id;
  String get docId => _docId;
}
```

#### todo_provider.dart

```
class TodoProvider {
  List<TodoModel> _todoList = [];

  Future<List<TodoModel>> fetchToDo() async {
    final result = await Firestore.instance.collection('todos').getDocuments();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    documents.forEach((document) {
      var data = {
        'title': document.data['title'],
        'done': document.data['done'],
        'id': document.data['id'],
        'docId': document.documentID,
      };

      _todoList.add(data as TodoModel);
    });

    return _todoList;
  }
}
```

#### error

```
E/flutter ( 5859): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5859): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'TodoModel' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5859): #0 TodoProvider.fetchToDo.<anonymous closure> (package:flutterbloc/resources/todo_provider.dart:21:26)
E/flutter ( 5859): #1 List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:285:8)
E/flutter ( 5859): #2 TodoProvider.fetchToDo (package:flutterbloc/resources/todo_provider.dart:13:15)
E/flutter ( 5859): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in Dart just create a Map and then cast it into a given object. You need to call the constructor of the class which you want a given object from. So in you case it should be:

```
      _todoList.add(TodoModel(
          document.data['title'] as String,
          document.data['done'] as bool,
          document.data['id'] as int,
          document.documentID as String));
```

I also want to add that your current `TodoModel` class can be simplified into this:

```
class TodoModel {
  final String title;
  final bool done;
  final int id;
  final String docId;

  TodoModel(this.title, this.done, this.id, this.docId);
}
```

If you only want to give read-access to a variable, and it will never change, you can mark it as final and let the public see it. It will be the same as making just a getter for the variable.

Dart also supports constructor parameters which points directly to the variable of the class it should initialize. So again, we can do that to make it more simple.

Comment: Thank you so much! Did not know this part
`need to call the constructor of the class which you want a given object from`
I really appreciate it!